# When an anchor to a form is clicked is the form then active? and can I then use :active in css to change a field in the form

Tags: html, css

When an anchor to a form is clicked is the form then active? and can I then use :active  in css to change  a field in the form?  My form and css below.  I hope that this can be done and that I am just referencing wrong. The reason I want this is that on my real page the link goes a long way down the page but there is nothing that shows it is active. Ideally I want a cursor or something to go to the first input but I will settle for changing the color of the input to yellow or something. I just thought it would be easier to figure this out with just a text change. Hope this makes sense.

```
<a href="#form2">Go to Section 2</a>

  <form id="form2" action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>  

 css
 form2:active > input > {    value: "George";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to modify the CSS of an input field when someone clicks on it, you can use the `:focus` selector.

**UPDATE**

if you want to trigger the focus on a field you can use for example:

`<a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].fname.focus()">Focus the field</a>`

you can also change the background of the form using

`<a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].style.backgroundColor='yellow'" ></a>`, as in this example:

```js
var link2 = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1];
link2.onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.forms[0].style.backgroundColor = '#c8f7c5';
  document.forms[0].fname.focus();
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
}

form {
  padding: 12px;
  transition: background 500ms ease-in;
}

input:focus {
  background-color: #fff68f;
}

.content {
  height: 200vh
}
```

```html
<a href="#!" onclick="document.forms[0].style.backgroundColor='#c8f7c5';document.forms[0].fname.focus();">focus the form using href="#!"</a>

<a href="#form2">focus the form using href="#form2"</a>

<a href="#form2" onclick="document.forms[0].style.backgroundColor='#fff'">unfocus the form</a>
<div class="content"></div>
<form id="form2" action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<p>
```

Comment: thank you @th31.  The problem is that I want the field to turn yellow before the user types in it. So it won't have the focus yet.  I thought that the whole form would be active after the link was clicked and that I could reference something to then happen with the form ie change a field to yellow. so that the user knows that the form is required next.

Comment: Hello, I just updated this answer, I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you.  It looks a lot different than what I started with.  I will try this out so that I understand it.

Comment: I do have a question on this.  on the first anchor href="#f" ....   Where exactly is it linking or going to? I don't have a form id named #f. If I change that to #form2 . #form2 field fname doesnt change color.  I am not sure if my thinking is correct but it looks like maybe it doesn't link anywhere.  Just changes the color .  Am I correct or wrong?  Thank you for your help. Hope this makes sense. I can't test it in my real page so I am using komodo to test and so little code that I can't tell if the form got the focus

Comment: I did not use the `href = "#form2"` to prevent the link from doing its default action which causes deactivation of the focus on the first input. Applying focus to the first input  will do the job of clicking on a bookmark link and will jump to the correct part of your website.
However  you can still use the correct href  `href = "#form2"` and disable the default behaviour of `<a>`, I will update the code to make two versions.

Comment: Again, Thank you.  that certainly is going above and beyond.  I will look at the updated now.  What I thought was that it was using the onclick to go to get the focus and that the href #f wasn't needed at all.  I need to look closer at which would be best practice.  A lot to learn.  Thanks again  The good thing is that you put me on a complete different process of how to do this. I somehow thought that I couldn't do an event on the form from the <a>  Again. so much to learn (and forget again) in my case :)  very helpful information.  Thanks

Comment: yes, exactly the `#f` wasn't needed at all (I have change it to `#!`) . you could change it with anything and it will still jumping to the form which has the `id="form2"` . You can also remove the href attribute and it will still work as expected.
My regards

Comment: I just tried it on MRP (My Real Page)  This is the program that our website is based on.  It has a user interface that I can add code to but I see that it isn't allowing me to add that code.  It deletes everything after the href "f"  I guess it can be used for nefarious purposes. Do you think that I should post another post asking for a work around without using JS? I am probably allowed to use javascript but that adds another layer of potential problems I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213047/discussion-between-th31-and-geddeca).